# collocation: learn information?

Tags: collocations

I was once told that "learn information" is not natural English. However, I see the following:

> Vygotsky scaffolding and the related concept of the zone of proximal development are teaching methods that can help students **learn much more information** much more quickly than they would with traditional instruction.

Is the above use correct?

Comment: It's often used. Attestations are to be found among the results here: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22learn%20information%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en   Any quibble would be on stylistic grounds.  We study the information to learn the thing to which it pertains.

Comment: While I have no quibble with the above, in any formal communication I would suggest **gather information** or **acquire information** (as well as absorbing, distributing etc......)

Comment: It would be better to base a question on some concrete research, rather than "I was once told".

Comment: @user3169 You could refer to any collocation dictionary. See the entry for "information."

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't exist. It needs to be in the question.